# Auto update cache in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have one problem when I using cache in Django.

Is it possible to load the page and update cache auto?

I don't want my first user wait when cache needs to be updated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a so called warm up script. This is just a script that opens the URLs you want to habe in the cache. Run this script as a periodic task. The simplest Version would be a shell script with curl statements in it tha is periodicly executed by cron.

The intervall with which you call it depends on your cache settings. If you configured to habe pages 10 minutes in cache calling the script every 10 minutes makes sure everything is always in the cache.

Comment: Thank you @Anton. It's a good way, but I am wondering if Django already include this function in the current version.

Comment: I am afraid it does not include this. I think warming up the Caches is not the job of Django. :-) Django can do a lot of things, but there is stuff outside of Django you need to implement yourself to have a truly great Website. But that's the fun part of being a developer isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I will try your suggestion. :)